# Column-specific context menu for Primefaces DataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, contextmenu

How can I define context menu for each column differently in Primefaces datatable? Putting `<p:contextMenu>` inside `<p:column>` does not work properly. I want context menu to be different depending on which column user right-clicked in.

This does not work (context menu is created the same for all columns):

```
<p:dataTable value="#{values}" var="value" selectionMode="single" selection="#{selectedValue}" id="table">
    <p:column headerText="Col 1">
        <h:outputText value="#{value.balance}">
            <f:convertNumber type="currency"></f:convertNumber>
        </h:outputText>
        <p:contextMenu>
            <p:menuitem value="Report"></p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Change"></p:menuitem>
        </p:contextMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="col 2" >
        <h:outputText value="#{value.balance2}">
            <f:convertNumber type="currency"></f:convertNumber>
        </h:outputText>
    <p:contextMenu>
        <p:menuitem value="Something else"></p:menuitem>
    </p:contextMenu>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

How to add column-specific context menu in Primefaces dataTable either by using PF components, extending PF components, or adding custom JavaScript?

Comment: Not yet. I am stuck on other assignment right now so it will be a few days before I can try @kian's solution

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried(I have just tested with Primefaces 3.5):
ContextMenu can be attached to any JSF component, each of rows in primefaces datatable has private and dynamic id(ex: :carList:0:test1  :carList:1:test1  ...), so I think you should use contextMenu inside column:

```
                 <p:column headerText="Model">  
                    <p:panel id="test1">
                        <h:outputText value="#{carr.model}" />
                        <p:contextMenu for="test1" widgetVar="cMenu">
                            <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search"
                                        onclick="product.showCellEditor();return false;" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close"
                                        onclick="cMenu.hide()" />
                        </p:contextMenu>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:column>  
                <p:column headerText="MANUFAC" style="width:20%">  
                    <p:panel id="test2">
                        <h:outputText value="#{carr.manufacturer}" />
                        <p:contextMenu for="test2" widgetVar="cMenu2">
                            <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search"
                                        onclick="product.showCellEditor();return false;" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close"
                                        onclick="cMenu2.hide()" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close"
                                        onclick="cMenu2.hide()" />
                        </p:contextMenu>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:column>
```

If you want to specify row:

```
<p:column headerText="Model" style="width:30%">  
                    <p:panel id="test1">
                        <h:outputText value="#{carr.model}" />
                        <p:contextMenu rendered="#{carr.model eq 'SENT'}" for="test1" widgetVar="cMenu">
                            <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search"
                                        onclick="product.showCellEditor();return false;" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close"
                                        onclick="cMenu.hide()" />
                        </p:contextMenu>
                        <p:contextMenu rendered="#{carr.model eq 'WAITING'}" for="test1" widgetVar="cMenu3">

                            <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close"
                                        onclick="cMenu3.hide()" />
                        </p:contextMenu>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:column>
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. This just puts a specific context menu per-column. not at all what i want.

Comment: Oh jeez. Sorry RongNK - I'm an idiot. I see that this question isn't even my question.

Comment: oh, that's funny, nothing at all :)

Comment: Here is my question which was falsely closed as a duplicate of this question by an idiot stackoverflow member: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099698/primefaces-contextmenu-different-menu-based-on-selected-item
Help me answer it and the 50+ is yours.

Comment: oh, you can set for specify row.

Comment: With me, reputation get no mean, i have tested it, and it work fine for me, i just want to help other people !

Comment: @RongNguyen Have you done contextmenu inside p:schedule? I cannot make it work when I nested contextmenu inside schedule.

Comment: @Halim Sorry, i do not worked with jsf for one year, so i don't have environment to test it.

Answer (score 4):

an alternative way is to use the p:menuButton instead.
the p:menuButton can be changed to look like a p:contextMenu
it's all about styleClass.

1. create custom styleclass to change the down arrow

   > ```
   > .contextButton .ui-state-default .ui-icon{
   >     background:url(YOUR_IMAGE_PATH);
   > }
   > ```
2. create custom styleclass to hide the button border and background

   > .**contextButton** .ui-button {   border: none;       background: none; }
   >
   > .**contextButton** .ui-button.ui-state-hover,  .ui-button.ui-state-focus, 
   >   .ui-button.ui-state-active {      border: none;   background: none; }
3. use the custom styleClass in the p:menuButton

   > <p:menuButton value="" styleClass="**contextButton**">
   >       P:MENUITEM HERE
   >   </p:menuButton>

you may refer [here](http://kianworknotes.blogspot.com/2013/03/workaround-for-primefaces-contextmenu.html) for working example

Comment: I like the idea - this is probably the closest approximation of what I need here. With some tweaking it should also be possible to trigger the menubutton on right-click thus simulating context menu. Will try this out and revert

Comment: I too think this is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Optional for attribute defines which component the contextMenu is attached to. When for is not defined, contextMenu is attached to the page meaning, right-click on anywhere on page will display the menu.

That's what [Primefaces Documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) says about the `contextMenu` tag. So, in the way you have, it's attached to the page meaning. Using *for* attribute you will be able to integrate with Primefaces Components, but probably no with an specific table column.

Also `Datatable` documentation suggests that you can only do that when making a selection into the table, as it seems it has special ways to adapt it to **tree nodes**.

However I highly recommend you looking through docs before asking.

Comment: I have tried "for" attribute as well - should have mentioned in the original question. Usually you can substitue "for" attribute with placing component inside the target component. Anyway, this results in error java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.component.column.Column cannot be cast to org.primefaces.component.api.Widget.

Still, it should be possible to attach the context menu to specific column by using custom Javascript code...