# Primefaces contextMenu different menu based on selected item?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a `p:dataTable` that I'm using in my app, and there is an associated `p:contextMenu`.

I'm wondering, how can you get the context menu options to be different based on the row selected?

For example, I have a Status row that is either SENT or WAITING. If SENT, i want the context menu to have one set of options, and if WAITING, i want the context menu to say other options.

how is this done with prime faces? Seems like basic functionality.

Comment: Since it is not possible to answer directly anymore, Nicholas, check http://kevindoran1.blogspot.com/2012/02/dynamic-primefaces-menus-menu-menubar.html What you need to do is to use MenuModel to generate conditional menu items. Additionally you can check http://kevindoran1.blogspot.com/2013/02/jsf-dynamic-menu-ii.html

Comment: That looks good! I'll try that today.